# How to set focus back to the original entry widget when a button is executed? (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am new to Python and tkinter...

I have been trying to *get the focus to set back to 'itemnum' when 'btn_add' is pressed.*
it didn't work though... the focus will stay on the 'lotnum' entry widget afterward.

i tried to used bind to event'' to make a new function def FocusSet

but still not working properly. I think I have issue passing arguments at this point..

Can someone point me to the right direction please? Much much much appreciated.
thanks!

The following is the script:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as tkMessageBox
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

ShowAddNew = Tk()


ITEM_NUM = StringVar()
LOT_NUM = StringVar()
UM = StringVar()

def ShowAddNew():
    global addnewform
    addnewform = Toplevel()
    addnewform.title("Mock Count/Add new")
    width = 230
    height = 260
    addnewform.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width, height, 0, 0))
    addnewform.resizable(0, 0)
    AddNewForm()

def AddNewForm():
    TopAddNew = Frame(addnewform, width=220, height=10, bd=1, relief=SOLID)
    TopAddNew.pack(side=TOP, pady=5)
    lbl_text = Label(TopAddNew, text=("Adding Count Result"), font=('arial', 9), width=220)
    lbl_text.pack(fill=X)
    MidAddNew = Frame(addnewform, width=220)
    MidAddNew.pack(side=TOP, pady=5)
    lbl_itemnum = Label(MidAddNew, text="Item Number:", font=('arial', 12), bd=6)
    lbl_itemnum.grid(row=0, sticky=W)
    lbl_lotnum = Label(MidAddNew, text="Lot:", font=('arial', 12), bd=6)
    lbl_lotnum.grid(row=1, sticky=W)
    lbl_UoM = Label(MidAddNew, text="U of M:", font=('arial', 12), bd=6)
    lbl_UoM.grid(row=3, sticky=W)
    itemnum = Entry(MidAddNew, textvariable=ITEM_NUM, font=('arial', 10), width=20)
    itemnum.grid(row=0, column=1)
    lotnum = Entry(MidAddNew, textvariable=LOT_NUM, font=('arial', 10), width=20)
    lotnum.grid(row=1, column=1)
    UoM = OptionMenu(MidAddNew,UM,"lb","kg","case","pk","unit")
    UoM.grid(row=3, column=1)
    btn_add = Button(MidAddNew, text="Save", font=('arial', 12), width=15, bg="#009ACD", command=AddNew)
    btn_add.grid(row=4, columnspan=2, pady=5)
    btn_add.bind('<Button-1>', lambda: FocusSet(itemnum))
    ITEM_NUM.trace('w', my_tracer)

    itemnum.focus_set()

    #UM.set("(Please Select)")
    TopAddNew.mainloop()  

def my_tracer(a,b,c):
        UM.set("loading...")


def FocusSet(event):
   itemnum.focus_set()


def AddNew():
    ITEM_NUM.set("")
    LOT_NUM.set("")
    UM.set("loading...")



ShowAddNew()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.mainloop()
```

YLH

Comment: Your `FocusSet` definition is not valid syntax. How do you expect `FocusSet` to know what `itemnum` is? Is it supposed to be an argument passed to `FocusSet`?

Comment: actually a typo, my apologies.

def FocusSet():
   itemnum.focus_set()

Comment: `itemnum` needs to be passed to `FocusSet` for it to know what it is. `tkinter` does not offer a "builtin" way to pass arguments to a function, so you need to use an anonymous lambda function which returns a handle to the function with the arguments passed. So, the `FocusSet` in your call to `bind` should be replaced with `lambda: FocusSet(itemnum)`. If you continue to have problems, please edit your post with a **minimal, complete, and verifiable example** since the code you posted is currently un-runnable.

Comment: I am still having issue.... I have just minimized my codes. I think I have issue in passing arguments with this script. Can you or someone point out my error please?
thanks in advance!

Comment: Call `itemnum.focus_set()` in `AddNew()` function.

Comment: Thanks Acw, but i did call the `focus_set()` in the `AddNewForm()`. It only set the focus the very first time user logged to the `AddNewForm()` page. I want to have the focus "reset" back to the `itemnum` Entry once `btn_add` button is clicked. how can I make this work?

Comment: i think right now my difficulty is to pass the argument from `AddNewForm()` to `FocusSet()` then back to `AddNewForm()` again... trying to get this right....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, thanks all :)
definitely the arguments was not passed correctly (still learning)
Cheers!

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as tkMessageBox
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

ShowAddNew = Tk()


ITEM_NUM = StringVar()
LOT_NUM = StringVar()
UM = StringVar()

def ShowAddNew():
    global addnewform
    addnewform = Toplevel()
    addnewform.title("Mock Count/Add new")
    width = 230
    height = 260
    addnewform.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width, height, 0, 0))
    addnewform.resizable(0, 0)
    AddNewForm()

def AddNewForm():
    TopAddNew = Frame(addnewform, width=220, height=10, bd=1, relief=SOLID)
    TopAddNew.pack(side=TOP, pady=5)
    lbl_text = Label(TopAddNew, text=("Adding Count Result"), font=('arial', 9), width=220)
    lbl_text.pack(fill=X)
    MidAddNew = Frame(addnewform, width=220)
    MidAddNew.pack(side=TOP, pady=5)
    lbl_itemnum = Label(MidAddNew, text="Item Number:", font=('arial', 12), bd=6)
    lbl_itemnum.grid(row=0, sticky=W)
    lbl_lotnum = Label(MidAddNew, text="Lot:", font=('arial', 12), bd=6)
    lbl_lotnum.grid(row=1, sticky=W)
    lbl_UoM = Label(MidAddNew, text="U of M:", font=('arial', 12), bd=6)
    lbl_UoM.grid(row=3, sticky=W)
    itemnum = Entry(MidAddNew, textvariable=ITEM_NUM, font=('arial', 10), width=20)
    itemnum.grid(row=0, column=1)
    lotnum = Entry(MidAddNew, textvariable=LOT_NUM, font=('arial', 10), width=20)
    lotnum.grid(row=1, column=1)
    UoM = OptionMenu(MidAddNew,UM,"lb","kg","case","pk","unit")
    UoM.grid(row=3, column=1)
    btn_add = Button(MidAddNew, text="Save", font=('arial', 12), width=15, bg="#009ACD", command=AddNew)
    btn_add.grid(row=4, columnspan=2, pady=5)
    **btn_add.bind('<Button-1>', lambda Event: FocusSet(itemnum))**
    ITEM_NUM.trace('w', my_tracer)

    itemnum.focus_set()

    TopAddNew.mainloop()  

def my_tracer(a,b,c):
    UM.set("loading...")


**def FocusSet(itemnum):
    itemnum.focus_set()**


def AddNew():
    ITEM_NUM.set("")
    LOT_NUM.set("")
    UM.set("loading...")


ShowAddNew()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.mainloop()
```